# Concatenar dos condiciones en un if

Tags: php

Estoy desarollando un pequeño script para woocommerce , donde según la geolocalizacion y categoria de producto , muestre u oculte el precio.

En este caso he conseguido hacer que funcione que mediante la geolocalizacion oculte el precio , pero esto es muy genérico pues afecta a todos los productos , mi objetivo es poder seleccionar en que categorias se aplica.

La primera opción funciona sin problema

```
 $userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
 if (($userInfo->city->name == 'Alicante' || $userInfo->city->name =='Bilbao')
 {
  codigo a ejecutar 
 }

else {

codigo a ejecutar 

     }
```

En este caso con has term puedo determinar en que categoria quiero que se aplique , pero por algun motivo me dice que sobra el primer corchete { , he revisado documentación y no soy capaz de encontrar el error.

```
 $userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
 if (($userInfo->city->name == 'Alicante' || $userInfo->city->name =='Bilbao') && ( has_term( array( 'pantalones',), 'product_cat')) 
{
codigo a ejecutar 
}

 else {

codigo a ejecutar 

 }
```

Comment: tienes `if (($userInfo->city->name == 'Alicante' || bla)`. ¿No hay un paréntesis de más después del `if`?

Comment: Lo que te falta es un paréntesis de cierre en el if. Prueba así: `$userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip(); if (($userInfo->city->name == 'Alicante' || $userInfo->city->name =='Bilbao') && ( has_term( array( 'pantalones',), 'product_cat'))) { codigo a ejecutar } else { codigo a ejecutar }`. Aunque yo no escribiría un código tan confuso... crearía variables y compararía las variables (lo digo por lo del array), o usaría un operador ternario.

Comment: Fran te propondría una solución más global, pero necesito entender exactamente qué es lo que quieres evaluar con el `has_term`...

Comment: has_term es la manera mas sencilla que he encontrado de poder filtrar en que categorias se aplica , soy nuevo en php y desconozco si hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo

Answer (score 3):

El siguiente código tiene una estructura correcta:

```
if ( /*Bloque de condiciones */ ) {
    //Código a ejecutar

} else {

    //Código a ejecutar 
}
```

Tu problema fue éste:

```
if (( /*Bloque de condiciones */ ) {
    //Código a ejecutar

} else {

    //Código a ejecutar 
}
```

Una doble apertura de paréntesis en la *sentencia **if***. Te sobró un signo de apertura de paréntesis. Sin embargo, PHP te dio un error de sintaxis, avisando de que encontró un signo de apertura { incorrecto, cosa que ocurre porque lo que espera es un cierre de paréntesis y no el signo que se encuentra.

Como la ejecución es secuencial, ***en los errores de sintaxis***, si no lo ves a primera vista, ***hay que mirar lo que precede a lo que te indica como error***.

Answer (score 2):

Yo propondría una solución global, que tendría las siguientes ventajas:

- La podrás usar desde cualquier parte del código.
- No te obligará a modificar el código (escribiendo además infinitos `||`) si tuvieras que comparar muchas ciudades, ya que recibirá un array de ciudades (`$arrCiudades`) para evaluarlas.
- Usará también un `$arrTerms`, que ofrece la misma ventaja mencionada anteriormente, en el caso de querer evaluar varios términos.

Construirás los parámetros fuera de la función, se los pasarás y la función te devolverá un resultado booleano (verdadero o falso), fruto de las dos comparaciones que debe hacer.

```
<?php 
    $userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();  
    $strCiudad=$userInfo->city->name;
    $arrCiudades=array ('Alicante', 'Bilbao');
    $arrTerms=array('pantalones');
    $strCategoria='product_cat';

    /*Aquí tendrás el resultado de la comparación*/
    $bolMostrar=mostrarPrecio($strCiudad,$arrCiudades,$arrTerms,$strCategoria);

    /*Esta es la función en sí, que podrías incluir en una clase utilitaria si quisieras*/
    function mostrarPrecio($strCiudad,$arrCiudades,$arrTerms,$strCategoria)
    {
        $bolMostrar=in_array($strCiudad,$arrCiudades) && has_term($arrTerms,$strCategoria);
        return $bolMostrar;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas!
La sentencia es correcta pero te sobra un paréntesis de apertura (justo después del IF). Este código sería correcto:

```
 $userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
 if ($userInfo->city->name == 'Alicante' || $userInfo->city->name =='Bilbao') && ( has_term( array( 'pantalones',), 'product_cat')) 
{
    codigo a ejecutar 
}

else {
    codigo a ejecutar 
 }
```

Si sigues teniendo problemas con el código prueba a utilizar || en lugar de &&.
Saludos.

Comment: Esta respuesta no es correcta,  tienes un `)` **justo antes** del `&&` el cual provoca un error de sintaxis. El error original es que sobra el `(` **justo después** del `&&` o falta agregar un `)` antes del `{`

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es que sobre un paréntesis en el inicio, sino que te falta uno al final.

```
( has_term( array( 'pantalones',), 'product_cat')) )<-
```

Si te fijas, el if comienza con el paréntesis "global" y luego abres otro paréntesis para la primera condición, luego del && abres el paréntesis para la segunda condición. En esta segunda condición luego del &&, abres 3 paréntesis pero cierras 3 también, te estaría faltando el paréntesis del if "global" que encierra ambas condiciones.
Quedaría así:

```
$userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
if (($userInfo->city->name == 'Alicante' || $userInfo->city->name =='Bilbao') && ( has_term( array( 'pantalones',), 'product_cat'))) //<- nuevo paréntesis 
{
codigo a ejecutar 
}

 else {

codigo a ejecutar 

}
```

En el primer bloque de código, que dices que si funciona, está sobrando un paréntesis al inicio

```
if (($userInfo->city->name == 'Alicante' || $userInfo->city->name =='Bilbao')
```